# What's wrong with my case statement syntax?

Tags: sql

```
select 
    nameLast + ',' + nameFirst as 'Name' 
from 
    Players

    CASE 
       WHEN bats = 'L' THEN 'Left'
       WHEN bats = 'R' THEN 'Right'
       WHEN bats = 'B' THEN 'Both'
       ELSE 'Unknown' 
    END AS bats
FROM Players
```

There is a syntax error with the "case" why? I have seen other examples that this is not an error.  What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow can you please be a bit more specific about the error and give some example-data to work with.

Comment: Why do you have two `FROM` clauses? What is `Players CASE`? Something is missing, and not inside `CASE`. Make a grammatical query without `CASE`, then add your correct `CASE` expression. Also note that, although it might not be needed in your specific case, you should still tag with DBMS engine you are using, per rules in [tag:sql] tag.

Comment: This SQL makes no sense at all - what are you trying to do?? Are you trying to select the `'Name'` and then the value from the `CASE` expression? Then why do you have a `from Players` after the `'Name'` and *before* the `CASE` ?? You should have  `SELECT` - then a list of columns (like `Name`, and your `CASE`), then a `FROM`, possibly `JOINs`, and optionally a `WHERE` and other clauses - having **two** `FROM` in a single SQL `SELECT` is utterly wrong

Comment: Remove the first `from Players` and the query should run.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `case expression` after `FROM` unless you dont have `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    nameLast + ',' + nameFirst as 'Name',
    CASE 
       WHEN bats = 'L' THEN 'Left'
       WHEN bats = 'R' THEN 'Right'
       WHEN bats = 'B' THEN 'Both'
       ELSE 'Unknown' 
    END AS bats  
FROM Players
```